# camel rest-dsl in conjuction with https and undertow component

Tags: apache-camel

Im trying to set up https for a few camel routes using the **undertow** component. Current camel version is 2.19.4. The code is from a minimal example:

The non-https-setup looks like this:

```
// setup    
restConfiguration()
    .component("undertow")
    .port(8888)
    .contextPath("/api");

// routes
rest("/hello")
    .get()
    .to("direct:hello");
from("direct:hello")
    .setBody(constant("Hello"));

rest("/world")
    .get()
    .to("direct:world");
from("direct:world")
    .setBody(constant("World"));
```

This works fine so far, I can access `http://localhost:8888/api/hello` and `http://localhost:8888/api/world` just fine.

Now, I configured my own keystore, created an `SSLContextParameters` object, and changed the setup part to this:

```
UndertowComponent undertow = (UndertowComponent) getContext().getComponent("undertow");
undertow.setSslContextParameters(getSslConfig());

restConfiguration()
    .component("undertow")
    .port(8888)
    .scheme("https")
    .contextPath("/api");
```

The route stays the same as before. Now, camel fails to start the server with the following error:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: https://0.0.0.0:8888/api/hello?httpMethodRestrict=GET
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.component.undertow.DefaultUndertowHost - Starting Undertow server on https://0.0.0.0:8888
[main] WARN org.apache.camel.component.undertow.DefaultUndertowHost - Failed to start Undertow server on https://0.0.0.0:8888, reason: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.19.4 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful shutdown 15 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
[Camel (camel-1) thread #18 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.component.undertow.DefaultUndertowHost - Stopping Undertow server on https://0.0.0.0:8888
[Camel (camel-1) thread #18 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: rest://get:/hello?componentName=undertow&routeId=route1
```

However, if I delete one endpoint, so that only a single route remains, all is well again. Obviously: only for that single route.

The same happens if I use the alternative syntax:

```
from("undertow:https://0.0.0.0:8888/api/hello?method=GET").to("direct:hello");
from("undertow:https://0.0.0.0:8888/api/world?method=GET").to("direct:world");
```

OK for a single one, failure for multiple routes.

How can I fix this? (BTW: first syntax is much preferred, as some common parameters like ports, tls-setup, scheme, base-path are held in one place. The real thing does have some more routes than just two.)

(Another remark that I noticed while playing around with the minimal example for writing this question: the problem seems to be specific to undertow. The jetty component works as expected.)

Answer (score 0):

Set a zero in your port, but you have to check the log in order to see what port number was assigned.